# Can Visual Studio be used to run C code with ARM scripts?

Tags: c, assembly, visual-studio-2015, arm, visual-studio-code

so I have these two files, one is a `.c` and one is a `.s`. These are just test files so I can get the hang of working C with ARM scripts, but for the life of me I can't get them to work together. I was wondering if I could make this easier by using either Visual Studio or VS code (or any other IDE if y'all know).

Here's my code:

ARM

```
.global add2
add2:
    stmfd sp!, {v1-v6, lr}  @ 'standard' entry, save registers on the stack
    add a1, a1, a2          @ do the addition requested
    ldmfd sp!, {v1-v6, pc}
```

C

```
#include <stdio.h> /* standard input and output */
#include <stdlib.h> /* standard library */
extern int add2(int i, int j); /* tell the compiler that the routine is not defined here */
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) /* entry point to the program */
{
    int i, j; /* declare the variable types */
    int answer;
    i = 5; /* give the variables values */
    j = 20;
    answer = add2(i, j); /* call the assembly language routine */
    printf("result is : %d\n", answer); /* print out the answer */
    exit(0); /* leave the driver program */
}
```

Currently the weird java program I've been using to link them is giving me the error

> "D:\Joe\College Stuff\CS 252\add.s:1: Error: bad instruction `ï»¿ .global add2'"

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: That ï»¿ part looks like file encoding issue.... Try using spaces to indent or don't indent at all and see what happens. What "weird java program"? Please specify!

Comment: This is not an "ARM script" - it looks like ARM assembly code (though I'm not familiar with the particular syntax - there are different syntaxes for the same underlying assembly language, e.g. AT&T vs Intel style, and others).

Comment: Visual Studio won't help you here - you need to learn how to run an assembler to convert your ARM assembly file into an executable ARM object-file and statically link it with your C program. Visual Studio's Visual C++ component is not actually a C toolchain (it doesn't even confirm with C99). You should use only command-line tools and seek instruction from your tutor/professor. Also are you sure you're meant to be using Windows? This kind of work is best done on a Linux system for their cross-compilation capabilities.

Comment: Our professor gave us some Java front end program that takes a c and ARM file and links them. According to him it is meant to be done on Windows, and if I wanted to learn how to compile and link files that way on command line, what would you suggest?

Comment: The GNU toolchain works well, and has no problem compiling C and assembling asm, and linking the result into a binary.  `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc  foo.c bar.S -o arm_binary`.  `.global add2` is a GNU assembler directive.

Comment: Is `ï»¿ .` from a Unicode byte-order mark or something?  If so, presumably your assembler doesn't support it, and you should configure your text editor not to put one at the start of text files.

Comment: @Dai I don't have any problems using an IDE on Windows to cross-compile for ARM, or download to flash, or source-level debug over the JTAG.  'You should use only command-line tools' is, at least, unhelpful.

Comment: @MartinJames I felt it would be helpful as the OP is a student and I'm sure we can all agree using the command-line to build is a better learning experience than an IDE's menu system.

Comment: Probably you misunderstand the whole assignment? Aren't you supposed to develop code for ARM using a Windows PC as development environment _and then download the program to an actual ARM processor?_ You must know if you have an ARM processor available or not. At the bare minimum you must know which class you are taking, is it about embedded systems or Windows programming?

Comment: @Lundin, it is an embedded systems class, but we aren't downloading into a ARM processor. We are just running it off Windows

Comment: @wjmccann Then you need some manner of simulator. You can definitely not use Visual Studio.

Comment: Ok so sorry for the long response time. We installed some "Codesourcery Lite" thing that seemed to add "arm-none-eabi". Unfortunately the documentation isn't very good. This is set up on my windows path, but I also think I can get it on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows as well. Any advice if y'all know how to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this error, configure your editor to not insert a BOM (byte order mark) at the beginning of the file. You might be able to do this by selecting “save as” and then selecting a different encoding (e.g. “ASCII” or “UTF-8 no BOM” or something like this). If you could tell us what editor you used to create the ARM assembly file, I could provide you with more specific help.

Comment: I used notepad to create the initial file, but from now on I'll probably use VS code

Comment: @wjmccann VS code should use the right encoding by default.

Answer (score 1):

For future people who come across this, **no**, you cannot run ARM scripts with C from visual studio. One way of doing it though is from the command line, which I found out from this question:

[Using the GNU ToolChain to Run ARM/C on Windows Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46571104/using-the-gnu-toolchain-to-run-arm-c-on-windows-command-line)