# Using the GNU ToolChain to Run ARM/C on Windows Command Line

Tags: c, bash, command-line, arm, gnu-toolchain

so you might recognize me from the other day when I asked a similar question about running this code in an IDE. Eventually the advice I got was that I should learn to run them together from the command line. As such I took the advice and installed the GNU toolchain from Codesourcery Lite MentorGraphics (not sure if that makes sense). The commands I can do are things like

```
> arm-none-eabi-gcc -o main main.c -T script
```

However I'm having trouble finding out exactly how I am supposed to use the commands. I tried

```
> arm-none-eabi-gcc -o main (my c filename).c -T (my ARM filename).s
```

But I get a syntax error from that in the ARM file. I then tried to do

```
> arm-none-eabi-gcc -o main (my c filename).c
```

But that doesn't work because of the external "add2"

```
> arm-none-eabi-as add2.s
```

That gets me a file "a.out" but I don't know what that does.

Here's my code:

ARM

```
    .global add2
add2:
    stmfd sp!, {v1-v6, lr}  @ 'standard' entry, save registers on the stack
    add a1, a1, a2          @ do the addition requested
    ldmfd sp!, {v1-v6, pc}
```

C

```
#include <stdio.h> /* standard input and output */
#include <stdlib.h> /* standard library */
extern int add2(int i, int j); /* tell the compiler that the routine is not defined here */
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) /* entry point to the program */
{
    int i, j; /* declare the variable types */
    int answer;
    i = 5; /* give the variables values */
    j = 20;
    answer = add2(i, j); /* call the assembly language routine */
    printf("result is : %d\n", answer); /* print out the answer */
    exit(0); /* leave the driver program */
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I also installed this toolkit from apt-get from Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, so if you have a BASH solution that could also be possible (https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/devel/gcc-arm-none-eabi)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: For which command?

Comment: for every command you are getting it.

Comment: `D:\Joe\College Stuff\CS 252\Homework>arm-none-eabi-gcc -o main addDrive.c -T add21.s
d:/mentorgraphics/sourcery_codebench_lite_for_arm_eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe:add21.s:1: syntax error
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

For the first command

`C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Temp\ccw6rCCg.o: In function main':
addDrive.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to add2'`


For the second one

Comment: `-T` is for linker script, not for assembly input.

Comment: What is the linker script used for? Is that to link the assembly to the C, or link the C to a compiler? Sorry if this is basic, I've never ran non python code from a command line before, so its new to me

Comment: if you comment out the add2 or replace it with something in the same file are you able to build a binary yes/no?  and run it?   then simply add the add2.s to your gcc command line along with helloworld.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone ever comes across this, the way I eventually got it working was to type these script lines into the Windows command-line:

```
Step 1: Compile your c-file
arm-none-eabi-gcc -o (object file name 1) -c (c file name)

Step 2: Assemble your ARM file
arm-none-eabi-gcc -o (object file name 2) -c (ARM file name)

Step 3: Link files and create executable
arm-none-eabi-gcc -o (executable file name) (object file name 1) (object 
file name 2) -T armulator-ram-hosted.ld

Step 4: Run the files
arm-none-eabi-run (executable file name)
```